# Why My 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' Request in Laravel Http Client Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i have an external API want to link to my laravel app as OTP service To Register System

The content Type of the API is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.
before link the api i try it in INSOMNIA and it works fine (see the picture below)

[image]

but in laravel app its not working , i try guzzle and Http client but for some reason its not working, and i think he is not consider the request as  **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.

My Code

[image]

The Message

[image]

Comment: In your example `defDate` is set in Laravel but not in Postman. double check that everything mathes both requests

Comment: defDate field accept Null value

Comment: I guess the problem is due to user agent, it is assuming the request is done on frequent interval, try to change the user agent header for the request

Comment: Try not sending a `defDate` in Laravel too or sending an empty value